# Why does the Dash app not preview in AWS Cloud9?

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, configuration, plotly-dash, aws-cloud9

Trying to view a Dash app in AWS Cloud9. From the Cloud9 docs (https://docs.c9.io/docs/run-an-application), the IP needs to be 0.0.0.0 and the only open ports are 8000, 8001, and 8002.

Set those ports in the run_server function, and also tried using the adhoc ssl with pyopenssl, to no avail.

I am running the file inside a python 3.6 virtual environment from the terminal.

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='Hello Dash'),

    html.Div(children='''
        Dash: A web application framework for Python.
    '''),

    dcc.Graph(
        id='example-graph',
        figure={
            'data': [
                {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [4, 1, 2], 'type': 'bar', 'name': 'SF'},
                {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [2, 4, 5], 'type': 'bar', 'name': 'Montreal'},
            ],
            'layout': {
                'title': 'Dash Data Visualization'
            }
        }
    )
])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)
```

I am still unable to view the Dash app in the preview pane in Cloud9.

Does anyone know the solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

For AWS Cloud9 preview ports are different: 8080, 8081, 8082.

See this doc for more information
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/app-preview.html